# Clickable icon inside a textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to insert an image inside a text box which should be clickable. Take a look at the code that I have written so far. I did create a class and inserted a background image to it.

Now, my question is how should I make it clickable?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.icon').click(function(){
    $('.text-here').innerHTML = "Please enter your username";   
  });
});
```

```css
.icon{
  background-image: url(http://directorzcut.com/modules/aqb/profile_mp3_player/templates/base/images/icons/popout.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.text-box{
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type = "text" class="icon text-box"/>
<p class="text-here"></p>
```

Only the area where the icon is present should be clickable is there a simple way to do it?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Where is icon, icon is not showing in the output

Comment: I'm so sorry I missed the css part. Let me edit it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can wrap the `img` with a `label` element with `for` pointer to the input.

When you click on the `label` the `input` will got focus.

I'm using `pointer-events: none` to disable focus on the `input` without clicking on the element. (`pointer-events` is **not** cross browser [can I use](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events))

Also, I fixed your js (`.html()` instead of `.innerHTML =`)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.icon').click(function(){
    $('.text-here').html('Please enter your username');
  });
});
```

```css
.input-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 5px;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 10px;
  margin-top: -5px;
}

.icon img {
  display: block;  
}

.text-box {
  padding-left: 20px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 250px;
  /*pointer-events: none;*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="input-wrapper">
  <input id="textbox" type="text" class="text-box"/>
  <label class="icon" for="textbox">
    <img src="http://directorzcut.com/modules/aqb/profile_mp3_player/templates/base/images/icons/popout.png" />
  </label>
</div>
<p class="text-here"></p>
```

Comment: This code is fine,  but the textbox is getting focused only when I click on the label icon. @Mosh Feu

Comment: Also the icon should work in responsive screens as well. That means whenever the textbox's size gets decreased the icon should be at the same position inside the textbox. Can this be done?

Comment: I thought that you want to enable the tetxbox only on click on the icon. Anyway I removed it. I also, changed the textbox's size and the icons stays at the same position relatively the textbox. If it's not ok, what do you mean?

Comment: Yes,  this is what I want now. Thank you :) @Mosh Feu

Answer (score 1):

Try this

**Html**

```
<div class="header-search">
                            <input  type="text">
                            <a href="javascript:;" id="link" >
                                <img class="img-seach" src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/hawcons/32/698627-icon-111-search-128.png">
                            </a>
                        </div>
```

**CSS**

```
input {
    border: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
    width: 86%;
    padding: 3px !important;
    box-sizing: initial;
}
.img-seach {
    position: absolute;
    right: 18px;
    top: 6px;
    height:14px;
    width:14px;
}
.header-search {
    width: 155px;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
}
```

**Script**

```
$('#link').click(function(){
    alert("clicked");
  })
```

[**Working fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/yzc2gfr8/2/)

Comment: Actually I do not want to use absolute positioning , Is there any other way apart from absolute positioning.

Comment: May be but I have only this solution @Harish

Comment: @Harish can i ask what do you have against `position:absolute;`? In you case it is the right direction, I've explained in my answer too.

Comment: Actually when I use absolute positioning the image is getting positioned inside the textbox as I need but it is not responsive.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$('.text-here').html("Please enter your username");`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.icon').click(function() {
    $('.text-here').html("Please enter your username"); // Only change this line
  });
});
```

```css
.icon {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  margin-bottom: -5px;
}
.text-box {
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="text-box" />
<img class="icon img-seach" src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/hawcons/32/698627-icon-111-search-128.png">
<p class="text-here"></p>
```

Comment: That's fine but only the icon area should be clickable. How do I do that?

Comment: @Harish then you have to create a separate icon element not in the input box.

Answer (score 0):

Background-image is not an element, and hence **is not** clickable. You should have the icon as a separate element, and assign the `click` handler to it.

The newly created icon element should be a sibling of the `input`, and be positioned on top of it using css, after giving the `input` element the proper `padding-left` value.

Check out this demo:

```js
$('#container .icon').on('click', function(){
  console.log('BOOYAAAA');
});
```

```css
#container {position:relative;}
input {padding-left: 20px;}
.icon {
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  top:4px;
  left:4px;
  width:13px;
  height:13px;
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <span class="icon"></span>
  <input type="text" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding, correct way is to have an `<img>` tag followed by `<input>` and wrap them in a `<div>`. Then, you will have to use css to update look so it appears as if image is inside textbox

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.icon').click(function() {
    $('.text-here').text("Please enter your username");
  });
});
```

```css
.my-textbox{
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.icon {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 4px;
}
.text-box {
  border: none;
  padding-left: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="my-textbox">
  <img class="icon" src="http://directorzcut.com/modules/aqb/profile_mp3_player/templates/base/images/icons/popout.png" />
  <input type="text" class="text-box" />
</div>
<p class="text-here"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

Right click on the icon and open it in new tab.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.icon').click(function(){
    $('.text-here').innerHTML = "Please enter your username";   
  });
});
```

```css
.icon{
  display:inline-block;
  background-image: url(http://directorzcut.com/modules/aqb/profile_mp3_player/templates/base/images/icons/popout.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left;
  position:absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  top: -1px;
  left: 7px;
  z-index: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
  color:blue;
}
.text-box{
  padding-left: 20px;
  position:relative;
}

.group{
position:relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="group">
<input type = "text" class=" text-box"/>
<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com" class="icon" target="_blank"></a>
<p class="text-here"></p>
  </div>
```